# Create button in class to use in another class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to dynamically create a button in a class to use it in my form class. To clear this up:

*this is where i create the button*

```
    class AddControls
{
   private Button _terug = new Button();

   public Button terug
    {

        get
        {
            return _terug;
        }
        set
        {

            _terug.Name = "btn_terug";
            _terug.Text = "terug";
            _terug.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            _terug.Enabled = true;
            _terug.Click +=_terug_Click;

        }
    }
```

*This is where i call the button*

```
    private void ShowStudents()
    {

        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(ac.terug);

        btn_cohort.Visible = false;
        btn_opleidingen.Visible = false;
        btn_showstud.Visible = false;
        btn_vakken.Visible = false;
    }
```

I've created an instance and it shows a button, but not with the set properties.

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you call to set?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?, in the second codeblock, the first line of code is where i want to add the button to my panel. If i'm right, is that where i call the set too, isn't it?

Comment: No ac.terug is a call to the getter not the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont you think you need a Property  - & you never call set.

Make a method which created the button which filles the properties you want.

```
private Button makeBtn(string caption)
{
   var button = new Button();
   button.Enabled = true;
   button.Visible = true;
   button.Text = caption;
   return button;
}
```

and later add a new button...

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(makeBtn("I'm alive"));
```

Comment: Terrific!!, this works like a charm, thank you so much, you just made my day :)

Comment: What's the `Caption` property? Did you mean `Text`? Never seen it before.